# Android Opengl doesn't render my display like emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, emulation, render

I recently i stumbled accross a weird problem(or at least i think so).I made in a little opengl es app for Android.The problem is that on the emulator it run's fine but on the phone it just doesn't render what the emulator showed me!
I tested the app on 2 devices:Samsung Ace and Sony Xperia x10 with the same result!
I just don't know what is the problem(i don't have too much experience with opengl on android) so please if you have some ideas... point me out
Some code:

Class that implements Renderer

```
public class GLOrbitor implements Renderer{
OrbitorLayer layer;
TexFont text; //this is used to render 1-9 and A-Z
TexFont text1; //this one to render a-z
int x;
int y;
private int atomNumber;
private int width;
private int height;
private Context context;

private final static float consty = 0.15f;

GLOrbitor(Context context){
    setContext(context);
}
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); // We know this is a 32bit font so set blending to suit
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        drawNumAndLetters(gl);   

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glPushMatrix();
        //gl.glTranslatef(-0.8f, 0.8f, 0f);
        layer.draw(gl,getAtomNumber());
    gl.glPopMatrix();


    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl.glViewport(0,0, width, height);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    float ratio = (float)width/height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, 1, 1, 3, 7);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    layer = new OrbitorLayer();
    text = new TexFont(getContext(),gl);
    text1 = new TexFont(getContext(),gl);
    try {
        text.LoadFont("ubunturegular.bff", gl); // 0-9 and A-Z
        text1.LoadFont("ubunturegular1.bff", gl); //a-z
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 1f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST | GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    //gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
}
```

}`

//this code draw a tiny rectangle

```
public GLRectangle(){
    setFilled(false);
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12 * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(6 * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mIndexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    float[] coords = {
            -poz, -poz, 0, 
            poz, -poz, 0,
            poz, poz, 0,
            -poz,poz,0
    };

    mFVertexBuffer.put(coords);
    short[] myIndecesArray = {0,1,2,0,2,3};

    mIndexBuffer.put(myIndecesArray);
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl)
{
    if(isFilled())
        gl.glColor4f(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    else gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

//and this one draw an array of rectangles

```
public class OrbitorLayer {
GLRectangle[] rectangle;
GLMargin margin;
private final static float consty = 0.15f;
OrbitorLayer(){
    margin = new GLMargin();
    rectangle = new GLRectangle[118];
}

public void draw(GL10 gl,int atomNumber){
    for(int i = 0;i<118;i++){
        rectangle[i] = new GLRectangle();
        if((i>=0) && (i<atomNumber))
            rectangle[i].setFilled(true);
    }
    //there's some exception for chromium with z = 24 and copper with z=29
    //they have 4s1 and 3d5 also 4s1 and 3d10
    if(atomNumber == 24){
        //4s2 is at 19 and 24
        rectangle[19].setFilled(false);
        rectangle[24].setFilled(true);
    }
    else if(atomNumber  == 29){
        //3d10 is at 29
        rectangle[19].setFilled(false);
        rectangle[29].setFilled(true);
    }
    gl.glPushMatrix();
        margin.draw(gl);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    int index = -1;
    float startx = -0.9f;
    float starty = 0.8f;
    //start with 1s layer
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        index++;
        //rectangle[index] = new GLRectangle();
        //translate and draw
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef((float) (startx + (i * 0.05)), starty, 0.0f);
        rectangle[index].draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
    //2 s layer
    startx = -0.9f;
    starty = (float)(0.8f - (1 * consty));
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        index++;
        //rectangle[index] = new GLRectangle();
        //translate and draw
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef((float) (startx + (i * 0.05)), starty, 0.0f);
        rectangle[index].draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
    //2 p layer
    startx = 0.7f;
    starty = (float)(0.8f - (1 * consty));
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        index++;
        //rectangle[index] = new GLRectangle();
        //translate and draw
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef((float) (startx + (i * 0.05)), starty, 0.0f);
        rectangle[index].draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
```

}

And a screenshot on  how it's rendered on emulator[image]
On a real android smartphone those filled rectangles and blue rounded shape aren't visible only the letters and number's which are drawn with these code
http://www.codehead.co.uk/cbfg/TexFont.java

If you have some ideas please don't hesitate!

---

**Update:**

Thank you Craigy and Matthew

Craigy:On a real phone i can't see those red and white little rectangles. Everything else work as exepected.By the way :only the the zone that fill the blue rectangle is an GLSurfaceView everything else has no link with opengl!Sorry if i can't provide a screenshot from a real device.My app was tested by  2 friends on their device's.

Matthew:the only thing where i use texture is displaying:1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and s,f,d,p.And what's funny is that they are rendered well on a real device.My question is why drawing texture's affects drawing and translating those rectangles.Anyway i will play a little more with the info you suggested me and i will let you guys now!

If you have any new intel about these problem...please i beg you..it's driving me nut's just displaying a few rectangles and some text give me so much problem's!!

Comment: Could you post screenshots of what it looks like on your devices?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying texture coordinates.

By default, the opengl implementation in the emulator doesn't do texturing correctly. By default it uses a 'fast' mode that blits the image without regard to texture coordinates. So your images show up on the 'incorrect' emulator, but don't work on a 'correct' device.

I'd suggest forgetting about the emulator for opengl development.

A few more things to keep in mind:

- The emulator will work with non power-or-two textures; the device won't.
- Android will scale images to match the density of the device, potentially resulting in your power-of-two texture ending up being non-power-of-two. Be sure to set BitmapFactory.Options.inScaled to false to prevent this.